# Combining two vba functions

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA functions in Excel (datecleanup and date1) that I would like to combine together into date1. Or preferably take the logic in dateclean and put into date1. This I'm sure is very simple, however I am new to VBA and not sure how I can accomplish this.

**datecleanup function:**

```
Function datecleanup(inputdate As Variant) As Variant

If Len(inputdate) = 0 Then
  inputdate = "01/01/1901"
Else
  If Len(inputdate) = 4 Then
    inputdate = "01/01/" & inputdate
  Else
    If InStr(1, inputdate, ".") Then
        inputdate = Replace(inputdate, ".", "/")
    End If
    dateclean = Split(strInput, Chr(32))(0)
  End If
End If
End Function
```

**date1 function:**

datecleanup = inputdate

```
Function date1(strInput) As String
 date1 = Split(strInput, Chr(32))(0)

End Function
```

I would like the date1 logic to occur as the final part of the dateclean function. How can I accomplish this? Thanks very much!

**EDIT:**

This is the correct datecleanup function:

```
Function datecleanup(inputdate As Variant) As Variant

If Len(inputdate) = 0 Then
    inputdate = "01/01/1901"
Else
  If Len(inputdate) = 4 Then
    inputdate = "01/01/" & inputdate
  Else
    If InStr(1, inputdate, ".") Then
        inputdate = Replace(inputdate, ".", "/")
    End If

  End If
End If

datecleanup = inputdate

End Function
```

Comment: Create a subroutine, or use an existing subroutine, and call both functions in the order you want them performed.  This may require using global variables to store the data between the two functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some cleaned up logic with it all combined into a single function:

```
Function datecleanup(inputdate As Variant) As String

    If Len(inputdate) = 0 Then
        inputdate = "01/01/1901"
    ElseIf Len(inputdate) = 4 Then
        inputdate = "01/01/" & inputdate
    ElseIf InStr(1, inputdate, ".") Then
        inputdate = Replace(inputdate, ".", "/")
    End If  

    datecleanup = Split(inputDate, Chr(32))(0)
End Function
```

Alternatively, you could keep them separate functions and just call the `datecleanup` function from within your `date1` function:

```
Private Function datecleanup(inputdate As Variant) As String
    If Len(inputdate) = 0 Then
        inputdate = "01/01/1901"
    ElseIf Len(inputdate) = 4 Then
        inputdate = "01/01/" & inputdate
    ElseIf InStr(1, inputdate, ".") Then
        inputdate = Replace(inputdate, ".", "/")
    End If  

    datecleanup = inputdate     
End Function

Function date1(strInput) As String
    date1 = Split(datecleanup(strInput), Chr(32))(0)
End Function
```

This is nice because it keeps the logic separate (if that's desirable here...)

Comment: I tried your first method, however I am getting a "Subscript out of range" run-time error. Any ideas?

Comment: I just edited the post above as the first function was not correct. If you wouldn't mind taking a look. It it giving that error for:  datecleanup = Split(strInput, Chr(32))(0).

Comment: Oh! of course it would. Sorry. Fat fingered that line. I have corrected.

Comment: And given your edit (it makes sense now... I was wondering how that would have even functioned before)... either one of these options should work.

Comment: Awesome this is great!!   Works as expected! I'm using the Split function because I have some data integrity issues with text being added into date fields. The Split function works great at capturing only the date as long as the date appears first in the string. However if Text appears first then the Split is returning back the first word, and ignoring the subsequent date in the string. An example is the string 'Mumps on 8/10/15' the split returns back 'Mumps'. Probably should be asked in another thread I'm assuming...

Comment: Probably would be a good idea. I would pop open a new question containing some sample data that contains all sorts of different ugly data that you are needing to parse to find that date and your current use of the split function and how that is unsuitable given the different types of strings you are dealing with.

Comment: @JBinson88 look into regular expressions, they'll help you match the pattern for a date inside a string. Especially if you have to put up with inconsistent datepart separators.